# TYPO3 10.4.20 and b13/containers

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I have installed b13/container extension on a typo3 10.4.20 composer installation. I want to replace grid elements with containers. Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/b13/container/blob/master/README.md) you can register a new Content Element by making a PHP call to TCA Registry. But after following all the steps it doesn't add a “Container” tab to the New Content Element Wizard.

Here is my tt_content.php

```php
<?php
    
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
    'tt_content',
    'CType',
     [
         'Great',
         'examples_newcontentelement',
         'content-text',
     ],
     'textmedia',
     'after'
 );

// Configure the default backend fields for the content element
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['eftmg_categorizedpages'] = [
    'showitem' => '
                --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
                    --palette--;;general,
                    --palette--;;headers,
                    selected_categories,
                    category_field,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,
                    --palette--;;frames,
                    --palette--;;appearanceLinks,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.accessibility,
                    --palette--;;menu_accessibility,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:language,
                    --palette--;;language,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access,
                    --palette--;;hidden,
                    --palette--;;access,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:categories,
                    categories,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:notes,
                    rowDescription,
                --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:extended,
            ',
    'columnsOverrides' => [
        'selected_categories' => [
            'config' => [
                'minitems' => 1,
            ]
        ],
        'category_field' => [
            'config' => [
                'itemsProcConfig' => [
                    'table' => 'pages'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

// Configure containers
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\B13\Container\Tca\Registry::class)->configureContainer(
    (
        new \B13\Container\Tca\ContainerConfiguration(
            'b13-3col-container', // CType
            '3 Columns', // label
            'Some Description of the Container', // description
            [
                [
                    ['name' => 'left', 'colPos' => 200],
                    ['name' => 'middle', 'colPos' => 201],
                    ['name' => 'right', 'colPos' => 202]
                ]
            ] // grid configuration
        )
    )
     ->setIcon('EXT:tourismus/Resources/Public/Icons/b13-3col-container.svg')
);
```

Maybe I have to downgrade my version to TYPO3 10.4.18?

Comment: In which folder did you put your tt_content.php? Does the rest of the file work (addTcaSelectItem and showitem of eftmg_categorizedpages)? Did you clear all caches (maybe also via Install Tool)? Did you check if EXT:container is really loaded, e.g. in the PackageStates.php file?

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at https://github.com/b13/container-example which provides an example container with 2-columns using TCA to add it into the NewContentElement-Wizard.

I'm also running on 10.4.20 and it works fine, might be your TCA for the container.. didn't test it but you should be good taking a look into the upper mentioned example.